# Sudden JavaScript syntax errors after Reinstall

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been having issues with the [Savsoft](https://github.com/Techkshetra/savsoftquizv6.0) Quiz software 6.0 nonstop. I was in the process of reuploading everything to my site because of some weird FTP error with my trash server host, and then suddenly everything stopped working completely, despite it being the same code as before. I'm receiving errors like:

'`custom.js:2577 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`'

'`dashboard.html:189 Uncaught ReferenceError: dashboard is not defined at dashboard.html:189:9`'

(The second one is probably due to the error in custom.js where the function originates.) I've run it through code checks, reinstalled the specific code from GitHub, checked all brackets and such myself too. But for some reason, it still says syntax error. Despite nothing really changing, I am completely lost. I even consulted AI which got me nowhere. If someone has a clue, I would greatly appreciate their insight. In the meantime, I'll keep trying different approaches to see if the issue is elsewhere. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Doing much more research into this, Now things are claiming to be a parsing error. However this code was working not even 48 hours before unchanged. You can take the code from the github link, specifically in application/dist/js/custom.js and throw it into any validator and it will error regardless of whats there. you could delete half the script and it will say the same thing.